# Undefined error when plotting from data

Tags: errors, plot

I have been trying to create a LaTeX plot for my own data. To get me started I have copied the code from [this website (ShareLaTeX)](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Pgfplots_package) into my TeX editor. All the graphs come out exactly like they look on the website except the one I want to model my own data on, namely the "plotting from data" (typical!!).

My question is:

What is it I am doing wrong here? I have used `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{pfgplots}`... I keep getting undefined control sequence when I enter the following code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.00in]{geometry}    
\usepackage{fixltx2e}    
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}    
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter

\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}
\usepackage{textcomp}{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
{\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}


\usepackage{setspace}    
\onehalfspacing    
\setlength{\jot}{2ex}    
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}    
\usepackage{cancel}    
\usepackage{stmaryrd}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}   
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}    
\usepackage{framed}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=120,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{textcomp}` in your preamble? `\textcelsius` needs it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. Finally, please make your code complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. As @Ignasi said, it may be your preamble that's the problem but we can't see it!

Comment: Thank you for your replies! Unfortunately it still hasn't worked. It keeps saying there is an error with the    \end{axis} line ...

Comment: My preamble is rather a mess but I will post it if it will help?

Comment: @AngusTheMan Absolutely it will help! You should also post the exact text of your error message

Comment: @darthbith Thank you for your help, I have entered my preamble into the question. (for some reason I can't get it to hi light properly, but its all there. The specific error is with the end axis line each time!

Comment: @AngusTheMan It would be better if you put the preamble into your first code you posted and included the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` just as you have in your file, so we can make sure nothing funky is going on. Anyways, you need to move the `\usepackage{textcomp}` from its current location. In the current location, it is in the middle of the macro definition and so not being loaded properly.

Comment: See here for how to create a proper minimal working example (MWE): http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/231/32374

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have also been trying to follow the prescription layer out in this      paperhttps://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-1/tb97wright-pgfplots.pdf    but as soon as I enter any text between the \begin{axis} and the \end{axis} I get error at the \end{axis} line .... I can however generate the empty axis

Comment: That's a great tutorial for `pgfplots`, but in this case your problem isn't due to something in `pgfplots`, its in your preamble. Does your document work now?

Comment: Sadly not ... I will delete my entire preamble and just start with the tikz and pgfplots packages and see if it works then... No idea what I'm doing wrong on this one :/

Comment: Didn't work ... so thats an entirely new document with only two packages and it still won't work ... hmm interesting

Comment: Then please post the exact error message you are getting! As Ignasi said, you need more than the `tikz` and `pgfplots` packages, you need `textcomp` as well! (And actually, `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, so you don't need to load `tikz` yourself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment: I get no errors with the following document. Note that I've removed all of the packages except the necessary `textcomp` and `pgfplots`. If you still have errors, please post the exact error message.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Solubility [g per 100 g water]},
    xmin=0, xmax=100,
    ymin=0, ymax=120,
    xtick={0,20,40,60,80,100},
    ytick={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (0,23.1)(10,27.5)(20,32)(30,37.8)(40,44.6)(60,61.8)(80,83.8)(100,114)
    };
    \legend{CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @darthbirth This Works !!! I can't thank you enough ... it has been driving me insane all day! thank you for your patience with me :)